# MySql DB from Ubuntu to RHEL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, migration, ubuntu, redhat

I would like to migrate my Mysql databases from Ubuntu to RHEL..what is the best way to proceed? I'm on community edition. I will be moving to entreprise edition of MySql on RHEL.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, why are you choosing MySQL Enterprise Edition? What does it offer you over the GA edition? I agree with @PhilSumner BTW.

Comment: Well.. Just assume I'm too rich :)

Comment: Very funny :-). However, my question was actually serious. It appears to me from my own experience that MySQL EE customers are few and far between. I am genuinely interested as to what were the factors that have made you decide on that path. Thanks for your input!

Comment: It has to do with licensing basically.. as an org we ought to go for EE.. there is much to risk on the compliance part.. does the GA feature has enterprise backup feature? I doubt it.

Comment: There's XtraBackup from Percona! :-) But, if you're redisributing, then you've no choice, unless you want to GPL your app!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hardware you're moving from/to (or not moving), you could just take the data & config files, and copy them across to the new system.  If the new system is set up the same for storage/memory, this might just work, but may need some tweaking of config to make it happen.

If you're changing to hardware where you can't just copy the files, then your only realistic option is a mysqldump export.